# Why declare a method in a Category without implementing it?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm reading the source code of an open-source project and I've encountered the following category definition in an implementation file:

```
@interface QCView (Private)
- (void)_pause;
- (void)setClearsBackground:(BOOL)flag;
@end
```

At first I thought that the `setClearsBackground` method was being *added* to the `QCView` class definition. But when I search through this implementation file, I find no implementation of a `setClearsBackground` method (although this message is sent to a `QCView` instance in a few places within the file).

Why would someone declare a method on a framework class like `QCView` but then not implement that method anywhere? My only guess is that this is a way to circumvent the compiler and call a method that isn't declared in the `QCView.h` file. But this seems unlikely, because how would the developer know that an implementation for this method even exists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The developer probably used a tool such as [class-dump](http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump/) in order to generate headers which list all the methods implemented by a framework.  This is useful if you need to access SPI and have no other choice.  Without the declaration, Objective-C makes assumptions about the method parameters and, beyond generating a warning, may generate an incorrect method invocation.

All the usual caveats about an undocumented interface breaking in a future OS revision apply.  At the minimum, you should check if the object responds to that method (`-[NSObject respondsToSelector]`).  For extra paranoia you can wrap the invocation in an exception block, in case the method remained but its behavior changed.

Comment: System Programming Interface.  Essentially, any (technically) externally accessible function or method that is not explicitly documented or supported.

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks. I downloaded class-dump and ran it on QuartzComposer.framework and the above methods do appear in the output, so I think it's safe to say that this is exactly what the author was doing. Thanks again.